# GIT Pull doesn't response via ssh

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh, git-pull

hello i have a ssh config with git pull

**ERORR MESSAGE: ssh: connect to host github.com port 5001: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**
my ssh config

```
 host *
 HostName github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_qch
 User git
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

My .git/config

```
 [core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = "ssh://git@github.com:Pagwebsa/qxxx.git"
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

I add the ssh key into settings > deploy keys into my github account

I try git status work fine, but
**when i try git pull, git clone, git fetch**
I don't get any response from github via terminal, no error message or another message

My ubuntu

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    **Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS**
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

I try via https but doens't work, i get message fatal autentication failed everytime, but the user and password works in web github

Comment: I'd recommend *not* using `host *` here, as that will match every `ssh` you run. Pick the specific GitHub names you'd like to match instead. (This probably has nothing to do with the *current* problem, but you're setting yourself up to have *future* problems.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your ssh config, add `Port 22` in order to make sure and contact GitHub on port 22 (instead of 5001).

Second, change your URL by

```
 ssh://git@github.com/Pagwebsa/qxxx.git
                    ^^^
```

Third, test first if your public key `~/.ssh/id_qch.pub` is registered, with

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```